# extract multiple values from json using json query ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have following output(snippet):

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "openstack_servers": [
                {
                    "az": "xxx",
                    "cloud": "xxx",
                    "created": "2019-10-14T09:42:42Z",
                    "created_at": "2019-10-14T09:42:42Z",
                    "disk_config": "MANUAL",
                    "flavor": {
                        "id": "s2.medium.4"
                    },
                    "has_config_drive": false,
                    "hostId": "78336513777de579fd80a528b9ace4a84bca0a725dd1dde5e7827309",
                    "host_id": "78336513777de579fd80a528b9ace4a84bca0a725dd1dde5e7827309",
                    "id": "d2fe3a68-44ec-4965-89bd-c792389bc7f7",
                    "image": {
                        "id": "ef7bf265-c69e-407d-8812-692f4a6ff6ab"
                    },
                    "interface_ip": "",
                    "key_name": "xxx",
                    "launched_at": "2019-10-14T09:42:59.000000",
                    "metadata": {},
                    "name": "QDETWR",
                    "networks": {},
                    "power_state": 1,
                    "progress": 0,
                    "project_id": "54026885c74446c2b833f4dc7cb77bd2",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
```

When I try to get status value:

```
      msg: "{{ output.ansible_facts.openstack_servers | json_query('[].status')}}"
```

It works fine.

I want to extract several values, but following doesn`t work:

```
      msg: "{{ output.ansible_facts.openstack_servers | json_query('[status, flavor, az]')}}"
```

or

```
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ output.ansible_facts.openstack_servers.content | from_json | json_query('[status, flavor]') }}"
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perusing the [documentation for the json_query Ansible filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) they do have an example that might be relevant to you.

Given a data structure:

> ```
> domain_definition:
>     domain:
>         cluster:
>             - name: "cluster1"
>             - name: "cluster2"
>         server:
>             - name: "server11"
>               cluster: "cluster1"
>               port: "8080"
>             - name: "server12"
>               cluster: "cluster1"
>               port: "8090"
>             - name: "server21"
>               cluster: "cluster2"
>               port: "9080"
>             - name: "server22"
>               cluster: "cluster2"
>               port: "9090"
>         library:
>             - name: "lib1"
>               target: "cluster1"
>             - name: "lib2"
>               target: "cluster2"
> ```

They provide an example to query it for multiple values, mapped as hashes to the resultant output.

> In this example, we get a hash map with all ports and names of a
>   cluster:

```
 - name: "Display all server ports and names from cluster1"
   debug:
     var: item   loop: "{{ domain_definition | json_query(server_name_cluster1_query) }}"
   vars:
     server_name_cluster1_query: "domain.server[?cluster=='cluster2'].{name: name, port: port}"
```

Note that they are only using `vars:` to define the query, ostensibly for readability, but the important bit is right there:

`domain.server[?cluster=='cluster2'].{name: name, port: port}`

So they're querying the domain.server (Which is a list of dictionaries, each with the same attributes), selecting only the ones with a `cluster` value of `cluster2`, and then for each of those returning the `name` as `name` and the `port` as `port`.

In your case, you want to return multiple attributes, but you don't want to select items with specific values. So you might use something more like:

```
msg: "{{ my_var | json_query('domain.server[*].{name: name, cluster: cluster}') }}"
```

The output I get back is:

```
    "msg": [
        {
            "cluster": "cluster1",
            "name": "server11"
        },
        {
            "cluster": "cluster1",
            "name": "server12"
        },
        {
            "cluster": "cluster2",
            "name": "server21"
        },
        {
            "cluster": "cluster2",
            "name": "server22"
        }
    ]
```

TLDR: Adapted to your specific question and use case, I believe what you want is:

```
      msg: "{{ output.ansible_facts.openstack_servers | json_query('[*].{status: status, flavor: flavor, az: az}') }}"
```

Thanks, hope that helps!